# How can I make a hover over an a tag not change color if that tag has a class of current?

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
  .navigation {
        a {
            color: #BBBBBB;
            &.current {
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            :hover {
                color: #EEEEEE;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way that I can make it so that when I hover over an address which has a class of current then it does not change the color to the hover color ?

Comment: It's neither HTML, not CSS. Looks like SASS. Do you don't know what you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the negation selector:

```
&:not(.current):hover {
  color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

Moe info about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 0):

use (`:not`):

```
        &:not(.current):hover {
            color: #EEEEEE;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/TCmCt/

```
a.navigation.current:hover
```